# ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC1 Docker with dnu publish

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have published an asp.net vnext application using,

> dnu publish --runtime 1.0.0-rc1-update1 --framework dnxcore50 --no-source

after this If I generate a docker container,

> FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-update1-coreclr
>
> ADD ./bin/output/approot /app WORKDIR /app
>
> EXPOSE 8080 ENTRYPOINT ["./web1"]

If I run this using "docker run" command, then I see there is a problem with System.Net.Security. I also read some related issues with deploying to Linux, + some blogs which instruct on how to do "dnu publish" with linux runtime in a LINUX OS (ex: Ubuntu).

If I have to build in a LINUX OS to target LINUX, then that beats the purpose of cross-platform. In some blogs I also read, just by doing dnu restore from the source it will be good enough, problem is I have a complicated source folder setup, and I don't want to write long build scripts for Dockerfile that will help me copy all the required source + dependent source projects, and then create a DNX image of the app (very tedious).

Does anyone have a simple solution for this?

Comment: Have you restored for linux? (i.e. did you use the --runtime parameter)? Do you have the linux runtime installed on the box you publish from? If you don't then publish won't have any place to take the linux runtime from?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was with the nuget packaging for System.Net.Security package. 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Security/4.0.0-beta-23516

This version doesn't include the package for dnxcore50, but the one previous to that has it defined,

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Security/4.0.0-beta-23409

Downgraded to use this and this issue is solved. Doh! silly issues by the MS team.